# Xamarin forms collection view minimum number of items

Tags: xamarin.forms, collectionview

I'm working with a CollectionView with a grid items layout. I would like to know if there's a way to show like empty "squares" (boxView/absoluteLayout...) depending on a minimum number of a source items **(binding it using MVVM)**.

I want something like this:

[image]

The minimum number would be 14, my items source has a length of 8, I add 6 "empty squares".

Is it possible to do something like this easily?

Comment: Are you using MVVM or Code behind?

Comment: MVVM sorry! I will update question

Answer (score 1):

You need two DataTemplates: one for the monkeys, the other for the empty box.

Make an interface ISquare, and implement it in a MonkeySquare and and EmptySquare.

Make the binded List of type ISquare and add 8 MonkeySquares and 6 EmptySquares.

In your Xaml make a DataTemplateSelector where you check if its the Cell is a MonkeySquare or a EmptySquare and return the belonging DataTemplate.
For more information regarding DataTemplateSelectors visit the [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/templates/data-templates/selector).